# Match objects to wildcarded strings in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Writing a script to get rid of certain Windows 10 bloatware and having some issues.

The intention is to check if the app exists before going ahead and removing it with  Remove-AppXPackage. I added all the names to an array of strings with and with asterisks on both sides but I can't get a match while using -like or -match in my if statement.

I wrote the code below to try to make it work exactly as the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage *windowsalarms* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

But instead, first check if that package exists. I'm assuming the original command is matching objects to eachother. And I'm realizing I'm trying to compare an object to string... So should I create an array of objects with just a name property for every single one and then try to compare them?

```
$AppsToRemove = @("*broker*"
                ,"3dbuilder"
                ,"windowsalarms"
                ,"officehub"
                ,"skypeapp"
                ,"getstarted"
                ,"zunemusic"
                ,"solitarecollection"
                ,"bingfinance"
                ,"zunevideo"
                ,"bingnews"
                ,"windowsphone"
                ,"bingsports"
                ,"xboxapp"
                ,"whiteboard"
                ,"sway"
                ,"todos"
                ,"lens"
                ,"soundrecorder"
                ,"onenote"
                ,"remotedesktop"
                ,"networkspeedtest")

Get-AppxPackage | ForEach-Object {

$Placeholder = $_.Name

    Foreach ($app in $AppsToRemove){

        If ($app -like $Placeholder) {
            Write-Host "Match"


        }else{
            Write-Host "No match"

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you seen `https://github.com/Disassembler0/Win10-Initial-Setup-Script`?

Comment: @KoryGill Thanks, I took a peek. But I was looking more for hints on how to do things myself. I rarely understand anyone elses code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this where you join your array into a [Regex] object. Then I got all the AppXPackages and piped that to a Where-Object to tell if they matched the original array. I added a `-WhatIf` at the end for testing. This can be removed when you want to actually run the script to remove them.

```
[Regex] $AppsToRemove = @(
    'broker'
    '3dbuilder'
    'windowsalarms'
    'officehub'
    'skypeapp'
    'getstarted'
    'zunemusic'
    'solitarecollection'
    'bingfinance'
    'zunevideo'
    'bingnews'
    'windowsphone'
    'bingsports'
    'xboxapp'
    'whiteboard'
    'sway'
    'todos'
    'lens'
    'soundrecorder'
    'onenote'
    'remotedesktop'
    'networkspeedtest'
) -join '|'

Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object -Property Name -Match -Value $AppsToRemove | Remove-AppxPackage -Verbose -WhatIf
```

I get the following output given that some of these are already removed on my machine:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Remove package" on target "Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_1000.16299.15.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove package" on target "Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_10.1804.1101.1000_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove package" on target "Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_10.1804.911.1000_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove package" on target "Microsoft.ZuneVideo_10.18082.10311.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove package" on target "Microsoft.ZuneMusic_10.18091.10321.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe".
```

Comment: LOL you to fast lol almost posted exact same thing haha. Wait no no mine is diffrent

Comment: i didnt see the wild cards in his array

Comment: lol, I removed the wildcards, i just left them in the first entry to test while debugging. I'll try this out in a moment. Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Oddly, when I run that, there is no output at all

Comment: @ShawnEsterman I ran it on a fresh user login. Maybe I misunderstood. I'm not well-versed with Regex commands or Regex as an object at all. I just ran what you wrote to see what would happen.

Answer (score -1):

The answer by @ShawnEsterman guided me to an idea that I'm more familiar with and I came up with the following that worked:

```
$i = 0
$AppsToRemove = @("broker"
                ,"3dbuilder"
                ,"windowsalarms"
                ,"officehub"
                ,"skypeapp"
                ,"getstarted"
                ,"zunemusic"
                ,"solitarecollection"
                ,"bingfinance"
                ,"zunevideo"
                ,"bingnews"
                ,"windowsphone"
                ,"bingsports"
                ,"xboxapp"
                ,"whiteboard"
                ,"sway"
                ,"todos"
                ,"lens"
                ,"soundrecorder"
                ,"onenote"
                ,"remotedesktop"
                ,"networkspeedtest")

$Packages = Get-AppxPackage | ForEach-Object {

Foreach ($App in $AppsToRemove){
    if($_ -match $App){

        Remove-AppxPackage $_
    }
}
```

}

Thanks Shawn for your guidance!

Comment: @ArcSet You mean because I call Get-AppxPackage 20 times? What if I do $Packages = Get-AppxPackage and use $Packages instead inside the loop.

Comment: I'm not really sure why yours works compared to mine, but I'm glad that you got a solution.

Comment: @ShawnEsterman I just went back and tried your solution, and it worked. Significantly faster than mine, even after I edited mine to be a bit more efficient. Could you perhaps explain how that Regex object works? Specifically, the [Regex] part and then -join '|' at the end is what is confusing to me.

Comment: Something is intermittent about it.. I tried it again on a different test account and i get no output, and all the apps are still there

Comment: Well I'm not sure why it would be working intermittently if you are copying and pasting it between computers. The script I wrote is pretty defined. Get-AllThings | Where Name -matches Something | Remove-ThoseThingsThatMatch